# Why is reverse proxy with Apache returning different results?

Tags: apache, next.js, reverse-proxy

Same url with remote server and local server return different things.

This is the local server bringing the content from remote server
[image]

This is the remote server original content[image]

```
Listen 443
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite ----hidden----
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:----hidden----(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLEngine on
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off

ProxyPass /_next https://profiles-three.vercel.app/_next
ProxyPassReverse /_next https://profiles-three.vercel.app/_next
```

This is my `apachectl -S` print

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   localhost (/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf:8)
*:443                  localhost (/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf:46)
ServerRoot: "/opt/bitnami/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
Main ErrorLog: "/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/error_log"
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/" mechanism=default 
PidFile: "/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
Define: USE_PHP_FPM
User: name="daemon" id=1
Group: name="daemon" id=1
```

Comment: Check that you are not double compress the output

Comment: Check if your node server / reverseProxy defining gzip